# Replacing a sticky header with a second header when it reaches the currently stuck header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been reading up on sticky headers and this is what I've found so far. The first sticky header works great but how could I scroll the first header up and make the second header stuck once it pushes the first header out of view when it encounters it?

http://jsfiddle.net/

```
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
  .fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .sticky {
    width: 100%;
    background: #F6D565;
    padding: 25px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
</style>

<p style="margin-bottom:100px;">Scroll this page.</p>
<div class="sticky"><h3>Super amazing header</h3></div>
<p style="margin-top:500px;">Still there?</p>
<p style="margin-top:500px;">Yep!</p>
<p style="margin-top:500px;">Scroll so hard!</p>
<div class="sticky"><h3>Super amazing 123</h3></div>
<p style="margin-top:500px;">Still there?</p>
<p style="margin-top:500px;">Yep!</p>
<p style="margin-top:500px;">Scroll so hard!</p>
<script>
var sticky = document.querySelector('.sticky');
var origOffsetY = sticky.offsetTop;

function onScroll(e) {
  window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? sticky.classList.add('fixed') :
                                  sticky.classList.remove('fixed');
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that the following will do *exactly* as you want...

The `#firstHeader` will bind to the top when scrolled past, and then when the `#secondHeader` collides with the bottom of the `#firstHheader` they will join and the `#firstHeader` will be pushed off of the screen until the `#secondHeader` reaches the top of the screen and binds there...

Hopefully that makes sense, if not, it'll probably be easier if you see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/yZKea/

This solution does use `jquery`. So you'll need to include a reference to it in your `head` before the rest of the `JS` code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**NOTE:** The `JS` isn't as *daunting* or as *long* as it looks, most of it is repeated setting of styles. You could easily change it to just a few lines :)

### CSS

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.spacer{
    height:200px;
    background:#f00;
    opacity:.5;
    border-top:#d22 5px solid;
    width: 100%;
}
#firstHeader{
    background:#00f;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:500;
}
#secondHeader{
    background:#0f0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:500;
}
```

### HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div id="firstHeader">Header 1</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div id="secondHeader">Header 2</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</body>
```

### JS

```
function scrollFunction(){
    var sticky1 = $('#firstHeader');
    var sticky2 = $('#secondHeader');

    sticky1.css({
        position: "static",
        top: 0
    });
    sticky2.css({
        position: "static",
        top: 0
    });
    $('body').css({
        "padding-top": 0
    });

    var topOffset1 = sticky1.offset().top;
    var topOffset2 = sticky2.offset().top;

    var stickyHeight1 = sticky1.outerHeight();
    var stickyHeight2 = sticky2.outerHeight();

    var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(topOffset1 <= scrollHeight && scrollHeight < topOffset2 - stickyHeight1){
        sticky1.css({
            position: "fixed",
            top: 0
        });
        sticky2.css({
            position: "static",
            top: 0
        });
        $('body').css({
            "padding-top": stickyHeight1
        });
    }
    else if(scrollHeight >= topOffset2 - stickyHeight1 && scrollHeight < topOffset2){
        sticky1.css({
            position: "fixed",
            top: - (scrollHeight - (topOffset2 - stickyHeight1))
        });
         sticky2.css({
            position: "fixed",
            top: stickyHeight1 - (scrollHeight - (topOffset2 - stickyHeight1))
        });
        $('body').css({
            "padding-top": stickyHeight1 + stickyHeight2
        });
    }
    else if(scrollHeight >=  topOffset2){
        sticky1.css({
            position: "static"
        });
         sticky2.css({
            position: "fixed",
            top: 0
        });
        $('body').css({
            "padding-top": stickyHeight2
        });
    }
    else{
        sticky1.css({
            position: "static",
            top: 0
        });
        sticky2.css({
            position: "static",
            top: 0
        });
        $('body').css({
            "padding-top": 0
        });
    }

}

$(window).scroll(scrollFunction);
```

---

### Updated JS

This should solve the problem with having a flickery screen.

```
var topOffset1, topOffset2;

function scrollFunction(){

    var sticky1 = $('#firstHeader');
    var sticky2 = $('#secondHeader');

    var stickyHeight1 = sticky1.outerHeight();
    var stickyHeight2 = sticky2.outerHeight();

    var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(topOffset1 <= scrollHeight && scrollHeight < topOffset2 - stickyHeight1){
        sticky1.css({
            position: "fixed",
            top: 0
        });
        sticky2.css({
            position: "static",
            top: 0
        });
        $('body').css({
            "padding-top": stickyHeight1
        });
    }
    else if(scrollHeight >= topOffset2 - stickyHeight1 && scrollHeight < topOffset2){
        sticky1.css({
            position: "fixed",
            top: - (scrollHeight - (topOffset2 - stickyHeight1))
        });
         sticky2.css({
            position: "fixed",
            top: stickyHeight1 - (scrollHeight - (topOffset2 - stickyHeight1))
        });
        $('body').css({
            "padding-top": stickyHeight1 + stickyHeight2
        });
    }
    else if(scrollHeight >=  topOffset2){
        sticky1.css({
            position: "static"
        });
         sticky2.css({
            position: "fixed",
            top: 0
        });
        $('body').css({
            "padding-top": stickyHeight2
        });
    }
    else{
        sticky1.css({
            position: "static",
            top: 0
        });
        sticky2.css({
            position: "static",
            top: 0
        });
        $('body').css({
            "padding-top": 0
        });
    }

}

$(function(){
    topOffset1 = $('#firstHeader').offset().top;
    topOffset2 = $('#secondHeader').offset().top;
});

$(window).scroll(scrollFunction);
```

---

## JS For variable number of headers

Simply add the class `.header` to your headers and this will work for any number of headers (1, 5, 100... You get the point).

This is a complete replacement for the above JS and each new header will *push* the old header off of the screen before it binds to the top.

See this updated `jsfiddle` for an example of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/5bkst/

```
var topOffset = new Array();

function scrollFunction(){

    var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop();
    var headerCounter = 0;
    var scrolled      = 0;
    var headerItems   = $('.header').length;

    $('.header').each(function(index, el){

        var elementHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

        var nextElementHeight = 0;
        var nextElement;

        if(index !== $('.header').length - 1){
            nextElementHeight = $('.header').eq(index + 1).outerHeight();
            nextElement       = $('.header').eq(index + 1);
        }

        if(scrollHeight >= topOffset[headerCounter]
            && (scrollHeight < topOffset[headerCounter + 1] || headerCounter == headerItems-1)){

            scrolled = 1;

            if(scrollHeight >= topOffset[headerCounter + 1] - elementHeight){
                $(this).css({
                    position: "fixed",
                    top: - (scrollHeight - (topOffset[headerCounter + 1] - elementHeight))
                });
                nextElement.css({
                    position: "fixed",
                    top: topOffset[headerCounter + 1] - scrollHeight
                });
                $('body').css({
                    "padding-top": elementHeight + nextElementHeight
                });
                return false;
            }
            else{
                $(this).css({
                    position: "fixed",
                    top: 0
                });
                nextElement.css({
                    position: "static",
                });
                $('body').css({
                    "padding-top": elementHeight
                });
            }

        }
        else{
            $(this).css({
                position: "static"
            });
        }

        headerCounter++;
    });

    if(scrolled == 0){
        $('body').css({
            "padding-top": 0
        });
    }
}

$(function(){
    $('.header').each(function(){
        topOffset.push($(this).offset().top);
    });
});

$(window).scroll(scrollFunction);
```

Comment: Yeah that works, but why does my screen flicker like crazy when I see it in action?

Comment: Possibly because it sets all elements to `static` (i.e. no sticky headers) to calculate some variables at the beginning of the function call. It shouldn't be noticeable though - unless, perhaps, you're on an older machine? I'll take a look at the code anyway

Comment: I rewrote some of the `JS` (see answer) with a slightly different method (some calculations are done once on page load as opposed to every time the page is scrolled) which should solve the _flickery screen_ bug.

Comment: What if my code is dynamically generated? I only have a single block of code with variables in it that make the headers and content repeat, so i don't have multiple headers in my code, only one header that holds a variable and then gets generated 20ish times variating between header-content-header-conten-header-content etc. How could it work with only one id attached to the sticky header?

Comment: I've added some more `js` to the answer... Just swap it out with the other `js`. This one will cater for an unknown number of headers (i.e. 1, 5, 50 etc). Note that I've used `class` as opposed to `id` (as it's applied to multiple elements). So your header tags will be something like: `<div class="header">Header 1</div>`

Comment: I have just updated the code _again_ because I forgot to add the `push off of the screen` feature. So it was just swapping the new header for the old header when the new header got to the top of the screen. While not a problem as such it meant that the new header was disappearing under the old header when it reached it (until it reached the top of the screen and replaced it). Anyway, the long and short of it is that the code above (accompanied with the new jsfiddle) should work correctly! (I don't think you actually saw the _bad_ code but I'm writing this comment just in case!)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to switch headers than try this. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/bvHAX/)

```
<header class="default">
  <div class="default-cnt">
    Default Content
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-cnt">
    Fixed Content
  </div>
</header>
```

---

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.default {
  background: #555;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}
.fixed {
  background: #01a8e7;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #000;
}
.default .fixed-cnt {
  display: none;
}
.fixed .default-cnt {
display: none;
}
```

---

```
$(function() {
  var header = $('header');
  var headOff = header.offset();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 120 + headOff.top && header.hasClass('default')) {
      header.fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('default').addClass('fixed').fadeIn('fast');
      });
    } 
    else if($(this).scrollTop() <= 120 + header.height() && header.hasClass('fixed')) {
      header.fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default').fadeIn('fast');
      });
    }
  });
});
```